# ComboBox.Dropdown Method only shows one list item

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm using a ComboBox in excel (vba) that adds items to the list based on what is typed (near matches) so that if what they are typing already exists in the data range, they can see it and click.

This is all working fine except for the method ComboBox1.DropDown, which is supposed to display the list. Unfortunately it only shows one item with the scroll buttons. Clicking the drop down button or pressing f4 shows the correct number of lines determined by the box's properties.

I've searched and searched, any clue how to show all items in the list automatically?

This is my first question on SO, please advise if tagged incorectly.

edit: ActiveX control, .listRows and .listFillRange do not seem to help

Comment: Where does `ComboBox1.DropDown` get called - `ComboBox1_Change()`? Is `ComboBox1.MatchEntry = 1` (fmMatchEntryComplete)? This is a UserForm and not ActiveX one right?

Comment: Yes .DropDown is called by ComboBox_Change(), but in a its own Sub that is dedicated to building the list.  .MatchEntry is set to none, I had issues because these lines:

    s = ComboBox1.Value
        ComboBox1.clear
        ComboBox1.Value = s

while clearing the list, was also setting the value of the box to the first matched value.

I definently should have mentioned it is a ActiveX control, I'll try a User Form and see if it acts differently.

Comment: Still need to learn how to format text on SO, I'll check out the documentation so I can separate code and comments.

Comment: Easiest way is to select codes to be pasted here, press tab, Copy, then paste in your Edit box. Why do you need to rebuild the list upon text change? Is it because the desired value may not be the first word user typing in?

Comment: Yea, users will need to know if the entry has already been made, so after 4 or so letters are typed, a drop down list should appear of existing names that include (or are close to) what they have entered.

The existing name may be different than what they expected it to be. Its important because a cross-reference number is generated for entries and its based on if the input already exists.

Comment: Had a tough time trying to set the properties of a user form dropdown box, I'd rather use ActiveX unless this just isnt possible. I may need to just take out ".dropdown" and inform users to click the dropdown periodically?  Can I send "F4" as a keystroke or somthing?

Answer (score 0):

I've been calling .DropDown in a custom Sub that creates the list, I needed to change it so it is now the last line in ComboBox1_Change().

Not sure why it acts differently in _change() than it did in my Sub (that was called by _change())!

I think that this is actually related to using the .clear method and then calling .Dropdown, it doesn’t recalculate how many lines to show. I may need to just keep them in separate Subs Thanks for your responses @PatricK

Edit: Not solved, it now works correctly with the first "change" more letters typed causes the rest of the list to stay un-cleared while the first row is updated and has the scroll buttons. I wish I knew exactly how these methods are written and when they get executed.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but when it comes to ComboBoxes, I never use the `Change` event, I use the `Click` event.

Comment: Interesting, I dont think that will fit my needs as I would like the list to change as you type.

Answer (score 0):

```
ComboBox1.Visible = False
ComboBox1.Visible = True
ComboBox1.Activate
If ComboBox1.ListCount > 0 Then
   ComboBox1.DropDown
End If
```

This code seems to do the trick, at least more than one line is diplayed, and the list is becomes shorter if items are removed, unlike before.